# Cannot parse file saved_model.pb: Error parsing message

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I found a MobileFaceNet pre_trained model:
https://github.com/sirius-ai/MobileFaceNet_TF

I want to load it into a keras object so that I can use `.fit()` and `.predict()` methods.

My code to load the model:

```
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model(model_dir_path)
```

And I got the error:

```
Cannot parse file 'saved_model.pb':  Error parsing message.
```

What happended ? How can I load and use this model ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Have you tried to understand the structure of the pretrained model? Did you try to check the accompanying library for this functionality? (https://github.com/sirius-ai/MobileFaceNet_TF/blob/master/test_nets.py)

Comment: I checked the accompanying libraries. But I can't understand the structure of the pretrained model. I don't have any knowledge on machine learning, just trying to find a model for developing my application. That's really frustrating for me

Comment: Oh and I downloaded and unzipped the dataset